# How to set the background transparent to a Nativescript webview?

Tags: webview, nativescript

I have a simple webview tag on my xml file, like this:

```
<WebView src="{{ content }}"/>
```

I've tried set the background-color to 'transparent' in the css file, also using inline css, but I can't get the webview background set to transparent.

More info about the project:
- nativescript version: 2.2.1
- I have a list of ticket's movements (like incidences about a particular case) on a support system app. This movements usually are html emails (with images, styles and so)... that's because I'm using a webview instead of an htmlview. As you can see in the image, the webview's background is white.

There's my xml snippet:

```
<!-- Repeat ticket's movs-->
<Repeater items="{{ movs }}">
    <Repeater.itemTemplate>
        <StackLayout>
            <StackLayout class="{{ movClass }}" visibility="{{ id != -1 ? 'visible' : 'collapsed' }}">
                <Label class="date" text="{{name + ' @' + dateValue}}"/>
                <WebView src="{{ content }}"/>
            </StackLayout>

        </StackLayout>
    </Repeater.itemTemplate>
</Repeater>
```

In the js file, I fetch the movements from an url and populate the array. 
If you need more info, please tell me and I upload it.

Thanks!

[BACKGROUND-NOT-TRANSPARENT-WEBVIEW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UD1PA.png)

Comment: Could you give some more info about your project and about your case?

Comment: Yes sure. I updated the description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make WebView with transparent background color you could use native code. For Android you could use `setBackgroundColor` method for Android to make background color transparent.  For iOS you should use `UIColor.clearColor()` to remove the webView background color. You could review the below attached sample code. In regard to that you should also add `tns-platform-declarations` plugin in your project, that would allow you to use some native methods in your typescript code.

main-page.xml

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" navigatingTo="navigatingTo">
<GridLayout rows="* 70 70" columns="*"  backgroundColor="green" >
    <WebView row="0"  loaded="wvloaded" id="wv" class="webviewStyle" src="
                  <html style='background-color: transparent;'>
                  <body style='background-color: transparent;'>

                  <h1>My First Heading</h1>
                  <p>My first paragraph.</p>

                  </body>
                  </html>" />
    <Label row="1" text="{{email}}" textWrap="true" />
    <Label row="2" text="{{password}}" textWrap="true" />


  </GridLayout>
</Page>
```

main-page.ts

```
import { EventData } from "tns-core-modules/data/observable";
import { Page } from "tns-core-modules/ui/page";
import { HelloWorldModel } from "./main-view-model";
import {WebView} from "tns-core-modules/ui/web-view";
import {isIOS, isAndroid} from "tns-core-modules/platform"


var Observable = require("data/observable").Observable;

var user = new Observable({
    email: "user@domain.com",
    password: "password"
});

// Event handler for Page "navigatingTo" event attached in main-page.xml
export function navigatingTo(args: EventData) {
    // Get the event sender
    var page = <Page>args.object;
    page.bindingContext = user;
}

export function wvloaded(args:EventData){
    var newwv:WebView =<WebView> args.object;
    if(isAndroid){
        newwv.android.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);//android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT);//
        newwv.android.setLayerType(android.view.View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }
    if(isIOS){
        newwv.ios.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor;
        newwv.ios.opaque=false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Does this still work for latest Nativescript? Any chance you could update it?

Comment: Yes, it should work. There is only a little change in the iOS API. The`clearColor` is no longer a method and should be called as a property of UIColor class. For example:`UIColor.clearColor`. The sample in my original comment is also updated.